# Block calls and SMS based on pattern

Tags: call-screening, sms-blocking

I use Callblocker currently, but the unwanted calls come from different numbers each with the same first 5 digits. Is there a way to block them based on this pattern, preferably free apps?

Comment: We prefer questions that are looking for a solution to a problem, not just "is there an app that does X". You've already selected your solution (an app) when there may be other ways to achieve the solution you need. Please have a look at the [FAQ].

Comment: Further, have you looked in the Play Store?