# How to block a range of phone numbers without any third-party apps

Tags: call-screening, sms-blocking

Is it possible to block a range of phone numbers

e.g. 02079460***

as I keep getting accident companies and personal injury calls.

I have read that these are fake numbers for  use in TV and radio dramas

Comment: I am ideally looking for a built in solution without having to install a separate app

Comment: Related: [Number recognition of company number ranges](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38055/16575) / **[Can I block calls based on a specific number prefix or pattern?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110470/16575)**

Comment: Yea that's all third party app's which cannot be installed on my work phone

Comment: Yupp, sure. I didn't say "duplicate" :) We like to link "related" question so people can find them easier. I was aware it's not exactly what you're after – sorry if that caused any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There's no functionality built into Android to do this. If you want to block a range of numbers, or numbers matching a pattern, and you can't install apps on the phone to do it (as per [Can I block calls based on a specific number prefix or pattern?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110470/16575) or [Free app to block calls and SMS based on pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35357/12442)), then all you can do is contact your carrier and hope that they can set up the block for you at the exchange. Carriers tend to be quite obliging about blocking nuisance callers, but of course they too may be limited by what software they have available, and they may just tell you to use one of the apps mentioned in the linked questions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is from 2 years ago but in case anyone is still wondering about this, I can say that at least on old LG smartphones like mine (LG Magna, also known as LG Magna H502F, H500F), it has built-in number blocking functions, and there you can block specific numbers, numbers that begin with the digits you specify and numbers that end with the digits you specify:

Android Version: 5.0.1

[image: IMG:]

UPDATE September 2020:

I have had two more LG smartphones (LG Q6, LG K51S) and they also have this same blocking features. Seems like this brand always have that function in their android systems.

Comment: On a Samsung Note II with Android 4.4.2 this can be done from: Phone / Menu / Call settings / Call rejection / Auto reject list / Create / Enter partial number and specify 'Match criteria'. On a Samsung Galaxy Note9 (Android 10): Phone / (Ellipsis) / Settings / Block numbers / Add partial number, select 'Match criteria' and tap the + icon to the right of the number.

Answer (score 0):

For Redmi PR MI phones

Goto Settings->search for blocklist -> open blocklist -> Click Block Numbers -> Click on Add -> Choose Add prefix
Now add prefix to add same number range